# servlet communicate with J2me Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, java-me

i am working with Eclipse to develop a application in J2ME.In This application i am using a servlet called HitServlet and a J2me Class HitMIDlet.
I want to run this project using Eclipse.But i do not what is the directory structure 
and how i make directory structure.
I am alredy configure J2ME plugin and Tomcat in my eclipse.
But i do not what is the directory structure of my classes in my eclipse.
To get the proper out put.
I want when i run j2me class(HitMIDlet)  it hit the servlet(HitServlet) and give the out 
put.

this is my J2me Class code:

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.microedition.io.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class HitMIDlet
    extends MIDlet 
    implements CommandListener {
  private Display mDisplay;
  private Form mMainForm;
  private StringItem mMessageItem;
  private Command mExitCommand, mConnectCommand;

  public HitMIDlet() {
    mMainForm = new Form("HitMIDlet");
    mMessageItem = new StringItem(null, "");
    mExitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
    mConnectCommand = new Command("Connect",
        Command.SCREEN, 0);
    mMainForm.append(mMessageItem);
    mMainForm.addCommand(mExitCommand);
    mMainForm.addCommand(mConnectCommand);
    mMainForm.setCommandListener(this);
  }

  public void startApp() {
    mDisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);
    mDisplay.setCurrent(mMainForm);
  }

  public void pauseApp() {}

  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {}

  public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable s) {
    if (c == mExitCommand)
      notifyDestroyed();
    else if (c == mConnectCommand) {
      Form waitForm = new Form("Waiting...");
      mDisplay.setCurrent(waitForm);
      Thread t =  new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          connect();
        }
      };
      t.start();
    }
  }

  private void connect() {
    HttpConnection hc = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    String url = getAppProperty("HitMIDlet.URL");

    try {
      hc = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
      in = hc.openInputStream();

      int contentLength = (int)hc.getLength();
      byte[] raw = new byte[contentLength];
      int length = in.read(raw);

      in.close();
      hc.close();

      // Show the response to the user.
      String s = new String(raw, 0, length);
      mMessageItem.setText(s);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
      mMessageItem.setText(ioe.toString());
    }
    mDisplay.setCurrent(mMainForm);
  }
}
```

and the servlet (HitServlet)

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HitServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private int mCount;

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    String message = "Hits: " + ++mCount;

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setContentLength(message.length());
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let Eclipse generate the directory structure. Create two projects. One for J2ME as *JavaME> MIDlet project* (assuming that you've correctly installed the [Mobile Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/) plugin) and other for JavaEE as *Web > Dynamic Web Project* (assuming that you're using Eclipse for Java EE and/or have installed [Web Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) plugin separately). Run the J2ME project on the mobile client and run the JavaEE project on Tomcat server.

#### See also:

- [Eclipse Mobile Tools documentation - Creating MIDlet project](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mtj.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/create_project.html)
- [Eclipse Web Tools documentation - Creating Dynamic Web project](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/twcreprj.html)

Comment: got this exception
Uncaught exception java/lang/IllegalArgumentException: Null URL.

Comment: That's a completely different and independent problem/question. Post a new Question about that. In this Question you're asking how to create a directory structure in Eclipse. I've posted an Answer for exactly that.

Comment: @BlausC sorry i want to ask as
At start i am saying that how j2me application communicat a servlet
and what is directory structure for them or it it is in different projects OR the both servlet and J2me class will be in one project.

Comment: In future questions, please try to [ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Although you didn't put question marks anywhere, I understood that you're asking how to create the project because you're stating "I do not know". I've answered that: create two projects using Eclipse's tools. I don't see anywhere in the question body a question about the problems you have, along with the exceptions/errors in detail. You should ask a new question about that. Or edit your question to clarify and I'll delete this answer. Once again: try to ask questions the smart way.