# J2me with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee, java-me

I have two classes one is J2me class HitMIDlet and a servlet HitServlet
i want to send request to servlet using J2me class.How i will mange these these two classes using Eclipse .?

Comment: *(FYI for others, this is a follow-up of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308541/servlet-communicate-with-j2me-project))* Sorry, this question is still too vague. The answer would basically be: *"Create two separate projects"*. You should describe the problems in detail. Describe the functional requirements and  copypaste the errors/exceptions/stacktraces. And last but not least, end questions with a question mark `?`.

Answer (score 0):

check this.
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Installing_Java_ME_development_tools_for_S60